# Keeping an instance of fabric.Image in a variable

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

First post here, because I cannot find any answer. I'm working on FabricJS, and I'm trying, for the need of my application, to build objects containing an instance of fabric.Image, and more specifically an instance obtained through the methode fabric.Image.fromURL() ([see here for more info](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-1#images))

Until now it seems to work, but if I console.log my object containing the instance of the image, I got an object of type "klass", which seems to have some image-related properties, but not all of them (no position, no source, no rotations, etc).

And when I'm trying to use fabric.Image methods on this object, I got errors concerning non-existing functions.

My question is the following : is this fact known ? Is there any mean to keep an instance of a fabric.Image anywhere else than in a canvas ?
I think my code is not very relevant to post here, but if needed I will sweep up my code to make it concise and show precisely what I want.

Thanks,
Cheitan

EDIT : I tried several other things. The most promising way to do what I want was to instantiate the image object from an URL, but instead of adding it to the canvas through the callback of the function, assigning it to an attribute of my custom object. Something like that :

```
var that = this;
fabric.Image.fromURL('img/myImg.png', function(img){
                that._image = img;
            });
```

But this is not working either, I got the following error from fabric.min.js :

> Uncaught TypeError: obj.setupState is not a function

I found several posts on this site or others concerning this error message but none of them are related to what I'm doing, it's more like JSON parsing and rebuilding fabric forms from it. Am I in a wrong way ?

Comment: Please make a jsfiddle & I will show you..

Comment: `.Image.fromURL` will create a Fabric Image object with fairly basic properties. If you want to assign properties (eg you mention position, rotation, etc) then you can do that during creation by sending in your desired properties wrapped in an object.

Comment: i think it should work. what properties or method fails? if you see few properties, open prototype and you should see them all

Comment: Gonna try to explain it simply. Here is a very small fiddle to show you my code, but it is not working, I never used jsFiddle before and I don't know how to use the library import feature : https://jsfiddle.net/sq07sts9/1/

As you can see I tried several ways to create my instance of fabric.Image in an object wrapped around it, but without success.

Of course this code is naked, I deleted what was not needed to understand what I want, but I think I'm still unclear... The last point missing is how can I create an object of fabric.Image.fromURL without placing it immediately in a canvas.

Comment: Anyway, the most promising way today is to use the second way of creating objects I showed in my fiddle. So what is this _obj.setupState_ error, and how can I avoid it ?

Comment: NEWS FROM THE BATTLE : I have no more errors, but there is some weird behaviour. Here is a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/sq07sts9/4/, all is explained line by line.